# Inner join order by performance issue in Android 2.3

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I have used sql select query in android app which works fine on newer versions of android i.e it takes 30 to 40 seconds on Samsung galaxy tab( android 4.0.3) to retreive data from sqlite database, but on device with older version of android 2.3 it takes 18 minutes to retreive data. If i remove "order by x_unitperson.UNITSEQ" then its performance do not decreases on android 2.3. How can i increase its performance on android 2.3 without removing order by clause.

My sql is:

```
SELECT PERSON_ID,
       COMMANDER,
       CITIZEN,
       RANK,
       GIVEN,
       SURNAME,
       ISOR,

  (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(NAME_SHORT, '\n')
   FROM units
   INNER JOIN
     (SELECT *
      FROM x_unitperson
      WHERE PERSON_ID = people.PERSON_ID
      ORDER BY x_unitperson.UNITSEQ) AS xunits
   WHERE units.UNIT_ID = xunits.UNIT_ID) AS NAME_SHORT,

  (SELECT FNAME
   FROM photos
   WHERE PERSON_ID = People.PERSON_ID) AS FNAME
FROM people
ORDER BY SURNAME,
         GIVEN
```

Comment: first: try to split the subselect statements and check which takes longer, "SELECT *" takes a bit more than "Select field1, field2" if not all fields needed

Comment: you query is quite complex. I would rather look into a way of simplifying it, may be load data progressively. Also, did you run an explain query plan on this query ?

Comment: do you have indices on these tables ? (indices can be used for ordering as well, if i remember correctly, see sqlite changelog)

Answer (score 2):

I am not that familiar with the SQLite optimiser, if a correlated subquery could be rewritten as a join some optimisers will create the same execution plan for both queries, and I am not sure if SQLite is one of these, so it may be worth converting your query to use JOINs rather than correlated subqueries, to see if it avoids:

```
SELECT  people.PERSON_ID,
        people.COMMANDER,
        people.CITIZEN,
        people.RANK,
        people.GIVEN,
        people.SURNAME,
        people.ISOR,
        ns.NAME_SHORT,
        Photos.FNANE
FROM    people
        LEFT JOIN
        (   SELECT  units.PERSON_ID, GROUP_CONCAT(NAME_SHORT, '\n') AS NAME_SHORT
            FROM    units
                    INNER JOIN
                    (   SELECT  UNIT_ID, NAME_SHORT
                        FROM    x_unitperson
                        ORDER BY UNIT_ID, x_unitperson.UNITSEQ
                    ) AS xunits
                        ON units.UNIT_ID = xunits.UNIT_ID
            GROUP BY units.PERSON_ID
        ) ns
            ON ns.PERSON_ID = people.PERSON_ID
        LEFT JOIN photos
            ON photos.PERSON_ID = People.PERSON_ID
ORDER BY people.SURNAME, people.GIVEN;
```

In addition (using what I can gather about your schema) I have removed all `SELECT *` from you query, this is bad practice in production code, I have also prefixed all column references with a table name/alias, again this safeguards your query against future schema changes.

Comment: I solved it my self using views. Created view of that query and retreived data from it beacuse "order by" in the query do not works properly on android 2.3.6 and takes too much time. Above works only on newer versions of android i.e higher than 2.3.

Comment: You should post your solution as an answer and accept it, it will help anyone else that visits this question who has a similar issue.